# netty getting the text value of an byte[]

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I use an API, that gives me the byte[] of a WebSicketFrame#content.
If I use WebSocketFrame#content#toString(Charset) is works with no problem.
The API I use although  returns WebSocketFrame#content#array, which returns the byte array.

I tried using new String(byte[]), which also tries to read the unreadable chars.
I Also tied this:

```java
ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytelist);
String message =  byteBuf.toString(Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
```

this also reads all the unreadable and writable chars.

Also:
ByteBuf#toString used on the ByteBuf from the original WebSocketFrame says is has a cap of 20
ByteBuf#toString used on the ByteBuf generated by Unpooled#wrappedBuffer(byte[]) says is has a cap of 16777216

I hope it is understandable what I try to describe

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `array()` returns the "backing array" of the whole buffer which may be a lot bigger then the readable portion of the `ByteBuf`. If you only need the readable portion of a `ByteBuf` as `byte[]` you should use one of its `readBytes(...)` method which allows to write into a `byte[]`.